# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'downlink')

Tags: javascript, chrome

im getting the above error. this is part of a chrome extension I made, but not sure how to fix this. Can someone pls help

```
  if (showConnection) {
    const speed = navigator.connection.downlink

    const connection = navigator.onLine
      ? (speed === 10 ? '> ' + speed : '~' + speed) + ' Mbps'
      : 'Offline'

    status += connection
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bread : Here , navigator.connection is `undefined`, You can add optional chaining operator as below -

```
navigator?.connection?.downlink
```

But you need to check why is it undefined and skip the entire block if its not defined.
Please modify your if condition as below :

```
if (showConnection && navigator?.connection) {

const speed = navigator?.connection?.downlink

    const connection = navigator.onLine
      ? (speed === 10 ? '> ' + speed : '~' + speed) + ' Mbps'
      : 'Offline'

    status += connection
}
```

Comment: @bread : Please refer this doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining